# How to move the hook with a curve

Tags: modifiers

I know how to move the curve with the hooks, but is there a way that hooks that are assigned to the curve , are moved by the curve.

Comment: using both a vertex parent and a hook together seems to bring undesirable results, but using the vertex parent is taking me to the right direction of what i try to make.
i try to go with the vertex parent and look how i manage !

Answer (score 4):

**Common parent.**

[image]

Give the curve and the hooks a common parent. Move the curve, and hence hooks relative to parent,  by moving the parent.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but unpractical.

You can do this with a *Hook* and a *Vertex Parent*, but it will create a position dependency loop, vertex position depends on the position of an object, and the object depends on the position of that vertex, this creates a logic loop, and becomes unstable rendering it unusable.

Select an object, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> Select the desired curve, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> > Vertex Parent.

This will create a relation between object position and a vertex.

Then still in *Edit Mode* with the vertex selected go to the menu *Control Points > Hook > Hook to Selected Objects*. This will link vertex position to the selected object.

[image]

You will now see that when you move the vertex in *Edit Mode* the object will move as well, and vice versa, but the movement will be increased exponentially, because blender is trying to keep both in sync simultaneously.

This will lead to hard to control results that are most likely not what you expect. A better solution is to stick to only one type on linkage, either just Hooks and manually update *Edit Mode* geometry positions, or stick with vertex parents, and refrain from editing in *Object Mode*.

Comment: Wow. I'm amazed the dependency graph lets you get away with this.

Comment: Wonder if this is even possible to solve elegantly