# Attach a single object to a single vertex of a mesh+skin

Tags: vertices, parent

See the image below. I have a plane I wish to attach to the end vertex of a "branch" (Note: the branch is a mesh, not a curve).

[image]

I've tried selecting the plane, then Shift + selecting the branch, going into edit mode, selecting the end vertex of the branch and then Ctrl+P and "Make Vertex Parent." This produces a bunch of instances along the branch, but I don't want those - I only want a single plane on the end vertex. I can disable instancing on the branch to get rid of the extra planes, but the original plane follows the root vertex on the branch, not the vertex I selected when I did the parenting.

[image]

How can I attach this single plane to a single non-root vertex of another object, and have it follow that vertex?

Edit: The suggested solution from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220460/how-to-move-the-hook-with-a-curve) doesn't work - it still parents the plane to the root vertex of the branch, not the vertex I selected.

Edit 2: I've discovered that the incorrect positioning seems to be related to my "branch" mesh, which is actually a line of vertices with a skin modifier. When I disable the modifier the plane/leaf attaches correctly to the end of the branch mesh. But when the skin modifier is enabled it flips.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like that's still tied to the root vertex motion. When I try what's described in the second answer (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220466/125759), I get the same behavior as I currently do - the leaf object gets tied to the root vertex of the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my issue was related to my strange mesh shape - just a line of vertices with a skin modifier. I was able to resolve my issue by instead using a cube and  parenting the plane to a vertex on top of the cube.